# MSI GF63 laptop does not wake up after SUSPEND

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, nvidia-prime, 23.10

System details:

- MSI GF63 laptop with GTX 1650MaxQ video card
- Xubuntu: Mantic 23.10
- NVidia driver 525.147.05; nvidia PRIME is set to on-demand

This laptop has trouble waking from suspend. I put it to sleep by closing the lid, and when i open the lid the screen stays black. I can do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a virtual terminal, and restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`. this doesn't seem to have any ill effects, but i'd rather not have to do this every time.

waking from suspend has worked in the past, but i can't recall the exact conditions it worked under; it was definitely an older version of xubuntu, and it may have been with the PRIME setting on "nvidia performance mode".

I don't have a good understanding of where to look for error messages; there are so many factors at work here: power management, nvidia drivers, PRIME, lightdm, etc. i'm not really familiar with troubleshooting any of these pieces.

I'd like some guidance on what log files to look at and what i should be looking for -- my goal is to have the computer wake up properly when the lid is opened.